# Display Folder Contents External of CFWheels Influence

Tags: coldfusion, cfwheels

My host provider has CFWheels set up as the root www folder I can access. However, I am trying to add a folder that is independent of the framework. In folder foo/ I added a blank application.cfc [as told here](http://cfwheels.org/docs/1-3/chapter/directory-structure) in the folder. But, when I upload the folder and try to view it on mywebsite.com/foo I get

**Could not find the view page for the `index` action in the `Admin` controller.**

Could the host have disabled my ability to do this? I also read that you can place files you don't want CFWheels to affect by adding them to `miscellaneous/` but want to avoid that if possible.

Answer (score 2):

Two things to check:

1) Have you excluded 'foo' in any URL rewriting files - i.e, .htaccess (apache etc) or web.config (IIS etc)? If you add it there it will bypass wheels easily.

i.e:

```
 Options +FollowSymLinks
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^.*/(foo|flex2gateway|jrunscripts|cfide|cfformgateway|CFFileServlet|cffileservlet|railo-context|files|images|javascripts|miscellaneous|stylesheets|robots.txt|favicon.ico|sitemap.xml|rewrite.cfm)($|/.*$) [NC]
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./rewrite.cfm/$1 [NS,L]
```

2) If you're not using url rewriting, then it might be there's a catchall route in your `config/routes.cfm` file.

Do you have anything with a wildcard there?

i.e

```
addRoute(name="catchall", pattern="*", controller="admin", action="index");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try putting some content in your /foo/Application.cfc file.

```
component {
    this.name = "foo";
}
```

Also, make sure the file name starts with a capital "A" - case matters on Unix/Linux servers.